# Dev/Prod Same container. Not seeing Same calls in GTM preview.

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm using the same container in both dev and prod version of the site, but not all 3rd party tags are firing for the dev as in prod. Trying to investigate the reason. Please Help!

Comment: Impossible to answer with that little info, but my guess would be you have Url based triggers and your dev/prod domains are different. Can you flesh this out a little so it becomes answerable (or makes it at least possible to determine if it's on-topic) ?

Comment: Yes, the urls a re different and figured this was the reason, I'm sorry if the question was brief.